# Angular 5 and jQuery plugin overwriting the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular5, flexslider

I am integrating a jQuery plugin inside Angular and having some issues

Plunker: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/pNCmYOo4vizJuj9V

Notice the slider slides are displayed correctly then plunker first loads, click on "toggle" button to change the slides and notice that now slider is permanently broken.

What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: you should avoid using JQuery in angular application.

Comment: I won't build my own version of flexslider though

Comment: if you want carousel you can use ng-bootstrap https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

Comment: https://github.com/devmark/ngx-slick

Comment: @Chellappan sometimes it's just **not** a choice :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  EventEmitter,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Input,
  ElementRef,
  AfterViewInit,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';

export interface FlexSliderSlide {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  image: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'flexslider',
  template: `
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="clearfix" *ngIf="_slides">
        <div flexslider class="flexslider carousel">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedSlide?.id === slide.id }" *ngFor="let slide of _slides" (click)="onSlideSelected(slide)">
              <div class="title">
                {{ slide.name }}
              </div>
              <div class="img">
                <img class="img-responsive" [src]="slide.image" [attr.alt]="slide.name" />
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .carousel {
      margin: 0;
      border: solid 1px #ccc;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .slides > li .img {
      cursor: pointer;
      border: solid 1px #ccc;
    }
    .slides > li:hover .img {
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    }
    .slides > li.selected .img {
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      border: solid 2px #00ccb0;
    }
    .title {
      color: #4A4A4A;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 16px;
      margin-bottom: 16px;
    }
    ::ng-deep .flex-control-nav.flex-control-paging {
      display: none;
    }
    ::ng-deep .flexslider ul.flex-direction-nav {
      position: static !important;
    }
    ::ng-deep .flexslider ul.flex-direction-nav a {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: -10px 0 0;
    }
    ::ng-deep .flexslider ul.flex-direction-nav a:before {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  `]
})
export class FlexSliderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private _slides: FlexSliderSlide[];
  // Most magic happens below...!
  @Input() set slides(v: FlexSliderSlide[]) {
    if (v && (JSON.stringify(v) !== JSON.stringify(this._slides))) {
      // ^-- Checks whether the model has somehow changed.
      console.log('triggering change');
      $(this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.flexslider')).removeData("flexslider");
      // ^-- remove existing data...
      this._slides = v;
      this.cd.detectChanges();
      // ^-- Force a redraw..
      this.ngAfterViewInit();
      // ^ -- Reinit the jQuery element.
    }
  }
  @Output() onSelected = new EventEmitter();
  selectedSlide: FlexSliderSlide;

  constructor(
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private el: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.flexslider')).flexslider({
      animation: 'slide',
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshow: false,
      controlNav: false,
      itemWidth: 250,
      itemMargin: 54
    });
  }

  onSlideSelected(selected: FlexSliderSlide) {
    this.selectedSlide = selected;
    this.onSelected.emit(selected);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Basically, this seems to be related to flexSlider itself, you can read more about it here: [Reload Flexslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807061/reload-flexslider)

Since it's not refresh-able, you must redraw the entire jQuery element each time the source changes, therefore you need to check whether the source has changed. To accomplish such, I just did a stringify check, you may implement a cleverer way to check whether the items changed (maybe id checks are enough?).
That said, after replacing the slides, you need to trigger the changed detection refresh so that the component gets redrawn, then you can call again the ngAfterInit to re-init the slider, and this will do the job beautifully.

Updated plnkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/L7yfcem2uz5UsYEO

Comment: Wow Thanks! I used a similar approach using  `ngOnChanges` and it's resolved!

Comment: Yep, the correct approach is indeed to use ngOnChanges, but using the setter is (as far as I know) correct as well, since the only property you need to care about (right now) is that one. Glad this helped :)